# How to implement onKeyDown in Fragment

Tags: java, android, fragment, onkeydown

I change all my activitys to Fragment. I got stuck in the onkeydown part.

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (!sector.getText().toString().equals("Sector") && (media.isChecked() || completa.isChecked())) {
        siguiente.setEnabled(true);
    } else {
        siguiente.setEnabled(false);
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

Comment: what you want to achieve ??

Comment: @HemantParmar I want to check if the EditText are not empty.
and if they are not, I want to enable the button to move on to the next Activity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by defining method in your fragment class. For example:

```
public void onMyKeyDown(int key, KeyEvent event){
 //define your statement like
 if (Integer.parseInt(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK) > 5
            && key == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK
            && event.getRepeatCount() == 0) {

     new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                .setTitle("Title")
                .setMessage("Do you really want to Exit?")
                .setIcon(R.drawable.logo)
                .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                        finish();

                    }})
                .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.no, null).show();
 }
```

}

Call onMyKeyDown method whenever a key-down event is raised in your Activity class. example:

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

        //call fragment method onMyKeyDown(keyCode, event)

    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```